# exiting a program with a cached exit code

Tags: python, c, caching

I have a "healthchecker" program, that calls a "prober" every 10 seconds to check if a service is running. If the prober exits with return code 0, the healthchecker considers the tested service fine. Otherwise, it considers it's not working.

I can't change the healthchecker (I can't make it check with a bigger interval, or using a better communication protocol than spawning a process and checking its exit code).

That said, I don't want to really probe the service every 10 seconds because it's overkill. I just wanna probe it every minute.

My solution to that is to make the prober keep a "cache" of the last answer valid for 1 minute, and then just really probe when this cache expires.

That seems fine, but I'm having trouble thinking on a decent approach to do that, considering the program must exit (to return an exit code). My best bet so far would be to transform my prober in a daemon (that will keep the cache in memory) and create a client to just query it and exit with its response, but it seems too much work (and dealing with threads, and so on).

Another approach would be to use SQLite/memcached/redis.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it really worth the effort? Does checking every 10 seconds use a relevant amount of system resources? Will it really be cheaper to have an extra process (or whole database system) hang around that does the caching?

Comment: Can you just write out data to a file?

Comment: @sth unfortunatelly yes, this prober must be scalable for 1000+ servers, in which case this would become a problem

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, yes. But that seems more complex than using something like SQLite.

Comment: I agree with @TheSoundDefense. The easiest thing to do would be to serialize a dictionary that contains the system health and last time.time() it was checked. At the beginning of your program unpickle the dictionary, check the time, if it's less then your 60 second time interval, quit. Otherwise check the health like normal and cache it (with the time).

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has really proposed anything I'll drop my idea here. If you need an example let me know and I'll include one.

The easiest thing to do would be to serialize a dictionary that contains the system health and last time.time() it was checked. At the beginning of your program unpickle the dictionary, check the time, if it's less then your 60 second time interval, quit. Otherwise check the health like normal and cache it (with the time).